# Regex unexpected result

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to check if the user input contains only 0 or 1 with Regex? But It also accepts different values.

```
inputChange = (e) => {
    console.log(/(^$)|[0,1]*/g.test(e.target.value));
};
```

The method above returns true for a string '222' but when I use online Regex checker it says that my Regex is correct.

Comment: where ? https://regex101.com/r/5szLXO/1/ .its working good

Comment: This one is simpler /[01]*/g

Comment: simply with `| => AND` operator `0|1` https://regex101.com/r/5szLXO/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why it is matching other values too ?

Well `[0,1]*`  here `*` means match zero or more time so in case of values other than `0 and 1` it still matches but `zero` time

So you can change `*` to `+`

```
/(?:^$)|^[01]+$/
    |     |__________  Matches string with only zero and one
    |     
    |________________  Match empty strings. ( Non capturing group)
```

```js
console.log(/(?:^$)|^[01]+$/.test('222'))
console.log(/(?:^$)|^[01]+$/.test(''))
console.log(/(?:^$)|^[01]+$/.test('1111111 111111'))  // fails because there's a space
console.log(/(?:^$)|^[01]+$/.test('010101'))
```

**On side note:-** You should not use `g` flag with test. read here [**why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results)

Comment: shouldn't 3rd case be returned true?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar if you see carefully there's a space between values

Comment: that's what i'm not able to know what exactly OP wants. because empty string returns true, so OP might want this case to return true.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar i guess OP is checking some input field which takes number as input. i guess some sort of `phone number without country code` or `quantity` something

Comment: Yes actually I want exactly the third case to return true but I modified your answer to /(?:^$)|^[01' ']+$/! Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: @Zotov you don't need `'` this, you can simply use `^[01 ]$`